# Jenkins scripted pipeline nested environment variable

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm using the Jenkins scripted pipeline and having trouble understanding how to nest environment variables within each other, here is a MWE:

```
// FROM https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-multiple-nodes

def labels = []

if (HOST == 'true') {
    labels.add(<HOSTNAME>)
}

def builders = [:]

for (x in labels) {
    def label = x

    builders[label] = {
        ansiColor('xterm') {
            node(label) {
                stage('cleanup') {
                    deleteDir()
                }
                stage('build') {

                    env.test = "TESTA"

                    env.intern = '''
                        TEST = "${env.test}"
                    '''

                    sh '''
                        echo $intern
                        printenv
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

parallel builders
```

The idea here is that `env.test` contains the value `TESTA`, which sets `env.intern` to `TEST = TESTA` this is what I want to happen. After this the code is just to print out the values.
Sadly the result is `TEST = "${env.test}"`.

How can I use nested string environment variables in Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax difference here is literal strings versus interpolated strings in Groovy versus shell interpreters within shell step methods.

- `"`: interpolated string in Groovy
- `'`: literal string in Groovy and interpolated string in shell interpreter

Essentially, a Groovy variable is interpolated within `"` in the pipeline execution, and an environment variable is interpolated within `"` in the pipeline execution and within `'` in the shell interpreter (and within the pipeline must also be accessed within the `env` object, but is a first class variable expression in the shell step method).

Therefore, we can fix the assigned value of `env.intern` with:

```
env.intern = "TEST = ${env.test}"
```

where the assigned value of `env.test` will be interpolated within the Groovy string and assigned to the `env` pipeline object at the `intern` key. This will then also be accessible to the shell interpreter within shell step methods, and the rest of your pipeline is already correct and will behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
env.intern = "TEST = ${env.test}"
```

As you're setting it now, the actual result of `env.intern` will be `"TEST= ${env.test}"`. So long as you set `env.test` before you set `env.intern` you should be good. Also, good to note that if you change the value of `env.test` then you need to reset the value of `env.intern` or it's going to hold the original value of `env.test` that it was set to.